# Flow to duplicate a button click

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, button

I have a flow that creates a record on a Transaction custom object. But to actually capture the transaction I need to click a button on the transaction page. The button launches a visualforce page that then launches a controller extension with some inputs. The extension is managed so I cannot call it in the flow. And flows can't access visualforce pages.

Is there another way I can get the transaction captured?

Comment: Doesn't the managed button also create a transaction record?  Is the Transaction object  part of the managed package, or your own custom object?

Comment: The button is on the transaction, it basically sends the info to the credit card processor. It is part of the managed package.

Comment: Luckily they provided a way to do trigger it automatically, it just wasn't on the page layout. If that wasn't an option I was going to try and build a trigger in apex that would emulate the button click when the record was created.